# When to use Taylor's theorem and when to use Maclaurin's

Tags: calculus

[image]

I'm a bit confused here about when to use Taylor's theorem and when to use Maclaurin's theorem.
Here,in this example they are using Taylor's theorem
Or

Please give me a rule of thumb to determine whether to use Maclaurin's or Taylor's
(tommarow is my test:)

Comment: Maclaurin is just a particular case of Taylor around a point $0$. Sometimes, you have to expand around a different point, or it's more convenient to do so

Comment: Didn't get it..

Comment: What is your understanding of Taylor's theorem?

Comment: Nothing...i just know how to expand functions using taylor's and maclaurin's function

Comment: It's not good. You should try to understand how and why Taylor works. But in any case, just as I said in my first comment: Maclaurin series is presisely the Taylor series around the point $x=0$.

Comment: Sir, any source you would recomment just to have essence of a topic without digging too much on the topic....

Comment: Not sure I can name any good source right now, you could google a little and see if you find something you understand. Now I have a question of my own: how does that textbook example you linked relate to your question?

Comment: We expand in maclaurin theorem and in taylor's theorem as well....since question was asking to expand :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the source of your confusion in this excersise.

It kind of looks like a mix between the general Taylor and the Maclaurin series, doesn't it?

Well, I'm going to make it clear: this is not Maclauring series.

Let's change the variable to:

$$t=x+y$$

So we are expanding $f(t)$ around what? By looking at the series, we can see that we are expanding around $t=x$.

Then the series should look like:

$$f(t)=\frac{f(x)}{0!}(t-x)^0+\frac{f'(x)}{1!}(t-x)^1+\frac{f''(x)}{2!}(t-x)^2+\frac{f'''(x)}{3!}(t-x)^3+ \cdots $$

But since we know that $$t-x=y$$ we can substitute it into our expression and work further to prove the addition formula.

---

For your test, you should at least have a firm grasp on the form of the series at arbitrary point and how to correctly substitute different variables there.

For your future studies, it would be very beneficial to understand the principle of Taylor expansion, which is better to do by looking at pictures and trying to understand the geometric point of view (for example, what is the geometric meaning of the derivative, do you remember?).